# Return email from Reddit with passport-reddit

Tags: node.js, passport.js, mean.io

I am working on implementing a Reddit login system on my node.js web server using passport-reddit. The system I have in place returns all of the information I need for my users except for their email address.
I am wondering if anyone in the community knows of a scope to include to tell Reddit to return an email address or if it's even possible.

My current Reddit routes:

```
// Setting the reddit oauth routes
  app.route('/api/auth/reddit')
    .get(passport.authenticate('reddit', {
      state: ' ',
      duration: 'permanent',
      failureRedirect: '/auth/login',
      //scope: ['email']
    }), users.signin);

  app.route('/api/auth/reddit/callback')
    .get(passport.authenticate('reddit', {
      failureRedirect: '/auth/login',
    }), users.authCallback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's question is quite dated, so is the answer I'll link to.  Seems that returning anything personal is against the "rules" of reddit.

https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/2lrcdv/oauth2_featureapi_request_being_able_to_see_the/

You can retrieve the username of the reddit user, no first / last name, email though.

Many other pieces of data are returned, but may not be useful to you.

```
 verified: false,
 over_18: true,
 is_gold: false,
 is_mod: false,
 has_verified_email: true,
```

ETC...